# How to copy turbo c++ output?

Tags: c++, windows, copy-paste, turbo-c++

How to copy turbo c++ output? I already Googled the problem but in vain. It says press print scrn and paste or right click and mark all and paste. I tried the both but not working. The problem is that it's only copying what is present on the current screen. But I want the whole screen from the beginning. (alt+printscrn not working either). How can I tackle this situation.

```
printScrn
Alt+printScrn
markall
```

none of them are working !!

for some reason i need this old way of programming i can't help with it but i would like to get a solution for the same . i have tried redirecting the output stream to the the file this way but it won't works .

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
const int max=50;
class dequeue{
int dq[max],r,f,c,x,i;
public:
dequeue();
void insertRear();
void insertFront();
void deleteFront();
void display();
};
dequeue::dequeue(){
f=r=-1;
c=0;
}
void dequeue::insertRear()
{
if((f==r+1)||(f==0)&&(r==max-1)){
cout<<"overflow";
return;
}
if(f==-1)
f=r=0;
else
{
if(r==max-1)
r=0;
else
r++;
}
cout<<"enter element";
cin>>x;
dq[r]=x;
c++;
}
void dequeue::insertFront(){
if((f==r+1)||(f==0)&&(r==max-1)){
cout<<"overflow";
return;
}
if(f==-1)
f=r=0;
else
{
if(f==0)
f=max-1;
else
f++;
}
cout<<"enter element:";
cin>>x;
dq[f]=x;
c++;
}
void dequeue::deleteFront(){
if(f==-1){
cout<<"deque empty";
return;
}
x=dq[f];
c--;
if(f==r)
f=r=-1;
else{
if(f==max-1)
f=0;
else
f++;
}
cout<<x<<"deleted!!!";
}
void dequeue::display(){
if(f==-1){
cout<<"dequeue empty";
return;
}
cout<<"\n"<<c<<"item in deque are:";
cout<<"\n(front)";
i=f;
if(i!=-1){
while(1){
cout<<" "<<dq[i];
if(i==r)
break;
if(i==max-1)
i=0;
else
i++;

}
}
cout<<"(rear)";
}
void main(){
freopen("output.txt","w",stdout); //this is not working
clrscr();
dequeue d;
int ch;
do{
cout<<"\n Menu";
cout<<"\n 1.insert at front";
cout<<"\n 2.insert at rear";
cout<<"\n 3.delet from front";
cout<<"\n 4.display";
cout<<"\n 5.exit \n";
cout<<"Enter your choice:";
cin>>ch;
switch(ch){
case 1:
d.insertFront();
break;
case 2:
d.insertRear();
break;
case 3:
d.deleteFront();
break;
case 4:
d.display();
break;
case 5:
exit(0);
break;
default:
cout<<"\n invalid";
}
}
while(ch!=5);
getch();
}
```

Comment: windows 8 and in XP have the same problem .

Comment: Is this from stdout? Did you try redirecting the output to a file? Pretty sure that will work even on MS-DOS 6.0

Comment: @user1023696: How are you running it, on a MS-DOS emulator? (and why are you using such an old compiler?)

Comment: yes i am on MS-Dos emulator

Comment: How the hell are you in an environment that can support Windows 8 but cannot support a compiler from this millenium?

Comment: You know you can get GNU g++ and Microsoft Visual Studio Express for free, right?

Answer (score 2):

I've tried one thing, and it worked, albeit it contains a handful number of steps.

- Compile and Run your program, and exit to the editor window
- Now, Go to "Window" tab menu > "Output"
- The Output window opens, now open the "Edit" menu > select "Copy" > then again open the "Editor" menu > select "Show clipboard"
- The Clipboard window opens up, now select "File" menu > "Save As", and save the file in a .txt file at an appropriate location.
- You can browse to that location in explorer to get the text file.

Answer (score 1):

You can always capture the output of a program by redirecting the standard output stream.

Suppose your program is called `exercise1.exe`. Then you can call it like that from the command line:

```
exercise1 >awesome.txt
```

Then you can simply open `awesome.txt` with the text editor of your choice and see the entire output.

Comment: http://blog.aditech.info/2008/02/saving-output-in-text-file.html  for some reason This is not working for me

Comment: Can you provide more information than "for some reason This is not working for me"?

Answer (score 1):

Run the Program. 
open the output using **Window->Output** .
then go to **Edit->Show clipboard**
then save the file with any other name
Then open **My computer/This Pc .Click on Local disk (C:)->TurboC4->TC->BIN** and right click on the name of the file select **Edit**
the file will open in **Notepad**
Then save the file as per your requirement using  **Save As** option.
Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Buddy,  follow these steps :-

1. Press PrintSrc on the output screen
2. The screen gets captured
3. You can only paste it a rich text document like MS-WORD
4. Then right click on the image inside the WORD and click on save as an image.

:-)

Answer (score 0):

1. Run your program.
2. Now Right Click on black screen
3. Select Mark option
4. Now Drag Mouse pointer to the Area u want to copy by pressing left
   mouse button. The area will be highlighted will while background.
5. Press Enter.
6. Open Your word document.
7. Select Paste option from Edit Menu (or Press Ctrl+v)